# Laravel post radio button

Tags: laravel, forms, button

I want to send the value of the radio button to the class, the problem is that the name is different each time because I have an id to finally group it in the view, how can I refer to this name?

```html
@foreach($users as $user)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>

    <td>
        <form method="post" action="updateprivileges/{{$user->id}}">
            @csrf 
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <input type="radio" value="1" class="flat" name="privileges_{{ $user->id }}" {{ $user->privileges[0]['roles_id'] == '1' ? 'checked' : '' }} > <div class="uprawnienia-margin">Administrator</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <input type="radio" value="2" class="flat" name="privileges_{{ $user->id }}" {{ $user->privileges[0]['roles_id'] == '2' ? 'checked' : '' }} > <div class="uprawnienia-margin">Serwisant</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <input type="radio" value="3" class="flat" name="privileges_{{ $user->id }}" {{ $user->privileges[0]['roles_id'] == '3' ? 'checked' : '' }} > <div class="uprawnienia-margin">Monter</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-primary input-lg" value="Przeslij" />
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: `$(document).on("click", "*[name*='privileges_']", function () { });` use jquery.

Comment: You can switch "value" with "name", so that the "name" for each radio button is the same, and the "value" is what you're currently passing in as the "name", and use a label for the radio buttons: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Comment: You forgot a `<td>` and syntax highlighting on your code block. I also editted your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

You have dynamic name attributes. You should change this to static ones, so you can always receive the correct value in your controller where you receive the payload. And don't forget to use the correct `HTTP Method`.

```html
<form method="post" action="{{ URL::to('/updateprivileges/' . $user->id)}}">
    @csrf

    <input type="radio" name="privilege" value="1"> Administrator</br>
    <input type="radio" name="privilege" value="2"> Serwisant</br>
    <input type="radio" name="privilege" value="3"> Monter</br>
    <input type="submit" value="Przeslij">
</form>
```

Declare the route in `routes/web.php`:

```php
// put method
Route::post('updateprivileges/{id}', 'UserController@updatePrivileges');
```

Now, your `UserController` receives the `privilege` variable in the `Request $request`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function updatePrivileges(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $privilege = $request->input('privilege');
        dd($privilege); // dumps $privilege and dies
        // more code, perhaps save the users privilege
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

You might want to check out [Laravel Method Spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#method-spoofing) and [Put, Post, Patch](https://blog.fullstacktraining.com/restful-api-design-post-vs-put-vs-patch/). Since you know the user (by id), you might want to switch to the `PUT` or `PATCH` method.

Comment: ok this is good, I have a problem with your solution, in the view, you have been given legal rights, now this is not happening ...